# Can't recycle the ERRORLOG - error 17049

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, clustering, error-log

When we attempted to run `sp_cycle_errorlog` we get the following:

> Msg 17049, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_cycle_errorlog, Line 9
>   Unable to cycle error log file from
>   'G:\SQL_DATA1\MSSQL10_50.ABC\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG.15' to
>   'G:\SQL_DATA1\MSSQL10_50.ABC\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG.16' due to OS error
>   '1392(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)'. A
>   process outside of SQL Server may be preventing SQL Server from
>   reading the files. As a result, errorlog entries may be lost and it
>   may not be possible to view some SQL Server errorlogs. Make sure no
>   other processes have locked the file with write-only access."
>   DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

So far we have tried:

1. Failing over the SQL cluster resource to second node, rebooting server, failing back and rebooting second node
2. Using Process Explorer tool - this identified the only process using the ERRORLOG file to be sqlservr.exe

SQL version details:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6000.34 (X64)  Aug 19 2014
>   12:21:34  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

There are two SQL instances on this two node SQL cluster, on the other instance the log cycles over with no issue.

I have seen a couple of posts on this subject but both appear to have been resolved by killing the non-sqlserver process. I'm presuming that the sqlsrvr.exe process is expected to be locking the file?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you stopped antivirus and tried running the procedure.

Answer (score 3):

From [System Error Codes (1300-1699)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): OS error 1392 indicates file corruption.

> ERROR_FILE_CORRUPT
>   1392 (0x570)
>   The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

So it looks like you have corruption on your G: drive.

I would start with a `chkdsk` of that drive and all other drives.

Since corruption usually doesn't fix itself and can have the tendency to worsen, personally I would fail over to the other node ASAP before other files (I don't know what else lives on the drive) corrupt and the situation gets trickier and trickier.